# Python Imaging Library loop performance getting slower with repetition

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have written a simple function to resize an image from 1500x2000px to 900x1200px.

```
def resizeImage(file_list):
    if file_list:
        if not os.path.exists('resized'):
            os.makedirs('resized')
        i = 0
        for files in file_list:
            i += 1
            im = Image.open(files)
            im = im.resize((900,1200),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            im.save('resized/' + files, quality=90)
        print str(i) + " files resized successfully" 
    else:
        print "No files to resize"
```

i used the timeit function to measure how long it takes to run with some example images. Here is an example of the results.

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Test Name     | No. files |      Min      |      Max      |    Average    |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Resize normal |     10    | 5.25000018229 | 5.31371171493 | 5.27186083393 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

But if i repeat the test the times gradually keep increasing i.e.

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Test Name     | No. files |      Min      |      Max      |    Average    |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Resize normal |     10    | 5.36660298734 | 5.57177596057 | 5.45903467485 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+

+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Test Name     | No. files |      Min      |      Max      |    Average    |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Resize normal |     10    | 5.58739076382 | 5.76515489024 | 5.70014196601 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+

+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| Test Name     | No. files |      Min      |      Max      |   Average   |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| Resize normal |     10    | 5.77366483042 | 6.00337707034 | 5.891541538 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+

+---------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| Test Name     | No. files |      Min      |     Max      |    Average    |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| Resize normal |     10    | 5.91993466793 | 6.1294756299 | 6.03516199948 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

This is how im running the test.

```
def resizeTest(repeats):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/dominic/Desktop/resize-test')
    files = glob.glob('*.jpg')

    t = timeit.Timer(
        "resizeImage(filess)", 
        setup="from imageToolkit import resizeImage; import glob; filess = glob.glob('*.jpg')"
    )   
    time = t.repeat(repeats, 1)

    results = {
        'name': 'Resize normal',
        'files': len(files),
        'min': min(time),
        'max': max(time),
        'average': averageTime(time)
    }
    resultsTable(results)
```

I have moved the images that are processed from my mechanical hard drive to the SSD and the issue persists. I have also checked the Memory being used and it stays pretty steady through all the runs, topping out at around 26Mb, the process uses around 12% of one core of the CPU.

Going forward i like to experiment with the multiprocessing library to increase the speed, but i'd like to get to the bottom of this issue first.

Would this be an issue with my loop that causes the performance to degrade?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `im.save()` call? I suspect the slowdown is due to repeated writes to the disk here.

Comment: Yeh the disk writes were causing it to slow down, when i removed the save, the times actually increased with each run. @MartijnPieters would you consider this function is suitable to be sped up with the multiprocessing module? im going to mark this questions closed.

Comment: If you have a computer with multiple CPU cores, using multiprocessing could well speed up the process (as each resize op is run on a separate CPU core).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `im.save()` call is slowing things down; repeated writing to the same directory is perhaps thrashing OS disk caches. When you removed the call, the OS was able to optimize the image *read* access times via disk caches.

If your machine has multiple CPU cores, you can indeed speed up the resize process, as the OS will schedule multiple sub-processes across those cores to run each resize operation. You'll not get a linear performance improvement, as all those processes still have to access the same disk for both reads and writes.

Comment: thanks @martijn, i will have a look into the multiprocessing module. It was interesting that moving the files and directory to an SSD didn't have much of an effect.